# Pausing a batch file as it is running

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My Windows 8.1 computer frequently shows a command screen for about half a second when connecting to certain WiFi connections. I'm sure it's just a connection script of sorts, but the fact that it disappears before I can see what it's doing has me curious.

Is there any way to pause batch files as they run, or be able to save them to a text file?

Comment: Hey Jason, I just edited your question to be a little clearer about what you're after and I changed the tags to get more appropriate visibility.  I hope this didn't change the meaning of your question, but if so, feel free to edit it again.

Comment: What are you clicking to connect?  A shortcut?  What is the target file of the shortcut?

Comment: I'm clicking the WiFi icon in the systray. Target is standard Windows networking. I'm talking about a script that executes AFTER connecting. I'm sure it's a proxy script of sorts, but I want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the script name/location, edit, and at the end :

Case it's a bat file :
- add : `set /p=Press any key to continue...`
Case it's a VBScript file :
- add :

```
msg = "Press any Enter key to continue... "
Wscript.StdOut.Write msg
Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfLine
   Input = WScript.StdIn.Read(1)
Loop
```

Otherwise, just push the "pause" button then any key repeatedly, until you catch "the moment"

Comment: Aihazm, my question was edited. I'm not trying to pause the script; the window disappears before I can get a chance. I don't know the name or location - it's a "mystery script" running infrequently. I am sure it's a bat file, as a black DOS screen appears for about 0.2 seconds. What I really need is something that will prevent ALL bat files from executing so I can find out what/where it is.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply: do you have any bat file un your startup folder?

Comment: Location:  c:\Users\<login name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup